# After creating a subsection, how to make a paragraph part of the parent section?

Tags: restructuredtext

The following is a block of reStructuredText that defines a "Main Section" and two subsections, each with a sentence of content.

```
Main Section
============

This is some main section content.

Subsection 1
------------

This is the content of subsection 1.

Subsection 2
------------

This is the content of subsection 2.
```

**Having created subsections, is there a way to add subsequent paragraphs that are part of "Main Section"?** E.g.:
The following is a block of reStructuredText that defines a "Main Section" and two subsections, each with a sentence of content.

```
Main Section
============

This is some main section content.

Subsection 1
------------

This is the content of subsection 1.

Subsection 2
------------

This is the content of subsection 2.

This is some more main section content -- I want this sentence to be "part of" "Main Section", not "Subsection 2".
```

Is there a way to do this? Or is it required that all of a section/subsection's content must appear prior to the addition of a subsection?

Comment: Why not cut-and-paste the content where you want it to appear?

Comment: @StevePiercy -- sorry, I'm not making the connection between your suggestion and what I'm asking...? My question is kind of: in the second code block, is `This is some more main section content ...` part of `Main Section` or is it part of `Subsection 2`? My understanding is that it is part of `Subsection 2`, and I was wondering if there is a way to make it part of `Main Section` _other than_ by moving it to above `Subsection 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, similar to sections in a typical printed book, this is not possible in reStructuredText. Neither the rST syntax nor the Dotutils document model provide for main section content after a subsection.

The "[topic](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#topic)" and "sidebar" directives provide for nested text parts with a title. They are intended for parts outside the main flow of the document and the title does not appear in the table of contents.

A transition may be used to denote a break after one or more paragraphs, although technically the part after a transition is at the same section level as before.